# string.IsNullOrEmpty returns true when supplied string is not null

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I have a unit test that calls a method on an object passing in a string.

One of the first things that the method being called does is to check the string for null or empty.

However, no matter what the value of filePath is, the call to string.IsNullOrEmpty is true.  See image below.

[image: Why is string null or empty]

Am I missing something here?

**EDIT:**

Checking for null and string.Empty separately works as expected:

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

I have cleaned the solution, deleted the bin directory via the file system and still, after a rebuild, the debugger shows that the ArgumentNullException should be being thrown, although it **actually is not being thrown**.

Comment: And the exception you get is really `ArgumentNullException`? Or is it some other exception that the debugger might show on the wrong line, for whatever reason?

Comment: Have you separately checked for Null and Empty? What are the results?

Comment: @hvd: I am throwing that exception

Comment: Is it possible that multiple threads are hitting your method and that you only see the state of one of the threads ?

Comment: filePath isn't defined at multiple levels in that class, is it?

Comment: @Maciej That wasn't what I asked :) It's possible for the debugger to show a line of code as if it's being executed, even if it isn't actually executed, usually (but not only) when building in Release mode. Your screenshot doesn't show that it's *that* exception that really gets thrown.

Comment: @b_meyer: no. this is a unit test

Comment: My guess is that your built assembly does not match your source code. Try a rebuild all, restarting VS, deleting any existing test results directory etc.

Comment: Add an `else` condition, force `filePath` to be a `null` or empty string and post the results of that test.

Comment: @Drasive: I have updated the question with your suggestion. Separately, filePath is not null and is not equal to String.Empty

Comment: You should really consider clear then rebuild solution. Have you done that?

Comment: @hvd:  You're right...it is stepping into there but the exception is not actually thrown...

Comment: @Deeko: I checked thoroughly for this case and it is not. A good call nonetheless.

Comment: Have you tried evaluating expression `string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath)` while being in debug (via Watch for example)? What did it tell you?

Comment: @Andrei: running via Immediate window, the expression evaluates to false.

Comment: Are you using a Release build?

Comment: Then apparently this is a problem with how debugger visualizes code execution. It seems that the code that throws exception itself is not executed. For double check you can temporary insert some more lines inside the `if`, something which execution you can actually check (console output, db writes, etc).

Comment: @svick: no. it is set to Debug

Answer (score 5):

The contents of `filePath` are definitely not null (and not empty), so that leaves us with two options:

- You have a wider scope variable (i.e. global variable) named `filePath`, which is empty on null
- Your debugger is referencing an older version of the binaries. In that case, claear and rebuild the solution

**Update**

Your question update makes me think the second option (of the above) is the one

Comment: I went ahead and cleaned the solution and rebuilt. Still, although the debugger shows that it is executing that line, it is actually not throwing the ArgumentNullException inside the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also experiencing this in Visual Basic with `If String.IsNullOrEmpty(foo)`. I agree with Andrei's comment, this seems to be a bug with how the debugger is visualizing this particular construct.

Clean/Rebuild did not affect it. Interestingly, if you add a more complex body to your `If` statement, the debugger will only pause (i.e. yellow arrow) on the *last line* of the body. It **does not** actually execute the line of code.

It would be interesting if someone could gives us some insight as to why this happens.

Here is the code where I'm seeing this:

[image]

Notice the debugger arrow is on the line `e.Cancel = True`, even though `myItem.Subject` is *not* null. When I press F10, the arrow will advanced to the ElseIf statement and `e.Cancel` will still be False.

Also, while the debugger is on this line, I cannot drag the arrow to a different line like I usually can. If I attempt to move to another line by dragging the yellow arrow, I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this is in a short but complete program that we can try? (It would help if you'd state the version of VS you're using, too...)

Comment: Huh, I didn't realize how difficult this would be to reproduce. I had assumed it was something that always happened or was specific to `IsNullorEmpty`, but I guess the prereqs are more specific than that. Added a bit more info (excuse the awful code, I didn't write it).

Comment: Are you able to get the code into a state where it doesn't require Outlook integration, and then post the code *as text*? Basically, I'd like to be able to copy/paste/reproduce...

Comment: Right. I posted it as an image to show the value and debugger highlighting. In any case, it's part of a huge project and I doubt copy/pasting this particular snippet would be useful. I will see if I can cull it without losing the behavior.

Comment: I cannot isolate the bug. There are too many dependencies. Any attempt to reduce the code essentially involves rewriting this function which eliminates the questionable behavior. Assuming I gave you a 10 line code snippet that could reproduce this, what would you do with the code? I'd be willing to attempt any ideas you might have on my large code base.

Answer (score 0):

This is the first time I have come across this issue.

The way we stepped round it for now is to add the following on the back of the IF statement.

```
#if DEBUG
            else
            {
                // A hack to fix the debugger issue on the IsNullOrEmpty statement above.
            }
#endif
```